# Which coding/term dictionaries for air pollution indexes

Tags: hl7-fhir, snomed-ct

It seems that neither LOINC nor SNOMED-CT have codes for air quality (such as the PM10, PM2.5 particulate measures, or nitrogen oxide or nitrogen dioxide).

Are there extensions which may cover these, or alternative coding dictionaries which may work?

Comment: LOINC and SNOMED are both aimed at clinical care rather than environmental values.  You could certainly propose adding such codes, but I'm not sure whether they would accept them as part of their scope.  You might also raise the question on chat.fhir.org to draw on the knowledge of a broader set of individuals.

Comment: Indeed - although both SNOMED and LOINC already contain codings for a great many environmental factors (e.g. cigarette smoke exposure, housing, etc...).
I'll check with the chat group. Thanks.